# Wordpress not retrieving a certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have the following code in an Wordpress template file (Goodwork theme) which outputs a list of posts.

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $v_filter == 'true' ? -1 : 12,
       'offset'=> 0,
       'paged' => $paged,
       'portfolio_category' => $custom_cat,
       'post_type' => 'portfolio');

$all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

The bit I'm having trouble with is `$custom_cat` which is set further above in the template like so:

```
$v_cats = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rb_meta_box_portfolio_set', true);

$all_cats = !empty($v_cats) ? implode($v_cats, ', ') : -1;

$custom_cat = isset($_GET['f']) ? $_GET['f'] : $all_cats;
```

The problem is that it's ignoring posts from a certain category.

If I change the code to `$custom_cat = 'promotions'` which is the name of the category not showing, then it outputs posts from that category, but not when pulling all categories.

Anyone have an idea why that might be?

In answer to BIOSTALL's question, the only other place that `rb_meta_box_portfolio_set` is referenced is in metaboxes.php where it's setting the Portfolio Post Type:

```
$rb_meta_box_portfolio = array(
'id'        => 'rb_meta_box_portfolio',
'title'     => 'Portfolio Options',
'desc'      => '',
'pages'     => array( 'page' ),
'context'   => 'normal',
'priority'  => 'high',
'fields'    => array(
    array(
    'id'          => 'rb_meta_box_portfolio_set',
    'label'       => 'Choose categories',
    'desc'        => 'Select the categories which will appear in this portfolio.',
    'std'         => 'portfolio',
    'type'        => 'checkbox',
    'class'       => '',
    'choices'    => $portfolios_array
    ),
```

Comment: May be problem is that, If category which have not any post not displaying in list.Please confirm this

Comment: Yes, the category does have posts. I stated that near the end of my post above.

Comment: It looks like you're using a custom meta box that sets the 'rb_meta_box_portfolio_set' post meta. Are you able to provide any more information about this and the options available, and maybe the code that saves these options too? I think the problem lies outside of the code provided so it would be good to see more of it. Thanks

Comment: I'm working with a theme that I didn't choose and am not that familiar with. All the content creation and most of the work in setting up the site has been done by someone else. I've just been called in to help out with a couple of niggling issues, one of which is this. I've updated the code in the post with all the other info I have about `rb_meta_box_portfolio_set`.

Answer (score 1):

Your implode() parameters are the wrong way round I believe

Answer (score 1):

Implode takes string first and then array, please check [php.net official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Please change your `implode` as following:

```
implode(', ', $v_cats)
```

thanks.

Comment: You're quite right, it was the wrong way around, but not the solution, unfortunately. If I echo out `$all_cats` it includes all of them except the missing one. I could do something like `$all_cats = $all_cats.',promotions'` but's that not very future-proof.